# Problem with generic interfaces referencing each other in C#

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I've declared two generic interfaces referencing each other:

```
public interface Interface1<A, B>
    where A : Interface2<A, B>
    where B : Interface1<A, B>
{
    A prop1 { get; }
}

public interface Interface2<A, B>
    where A : Interface2<A, B>
    where B : Interface1<A, B>
{
    IEnumerable<B> prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

The problem arises when i try to use one of the interfaces as a return type in a method. For example:

```
public class test
{
    public Interface1<Interface2<>>...> MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

The return type of MyMethod() becomes circular so I can't use the interface as a return type.

What should I do?

**EDIT:** Thanks to all. Here is my full requirement:

I'm working with Entity Framework, and I have two entity classes that relate to each other through navigation properties. Both entity classes already inherit from a base class (common to all the entities in my app).

Because this a multi-tenant app, each class could have different properties / fields for each tenant, but all have some common properties that are used along common functionality of the app.

Therefore I added (to avoid proxy classes) an interface to each entity class.

This is the extended code:

```
public interface Interface1<A, B>
    where A : Interface2<A, B>
    where B : Interface1<A, B>
{
    A dog { get; set; }
}

public interface Interface2<A, B>
    where A : Interface2<A, B>
    where B : Interface1<A, B>
{
    IEnumerable<B> dogs { get;  }
}

public class Entity1: myEntityBaseClass, Interface1<Entity2,Entity1>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Entity2 dog { get; set; }
}

public class Entity2 : myEntityBaseClass, Interface2<Entity2, Entity1>
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Entity1> dogs { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<Entity1>  Interface2<Entity2, Entity1>.dogs { get { return dogs; } }
}

public class test
{
    public Interface1<Interface2<>>....> MyMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your requirement.Your design going in another way

Comment: i added aditional info based on your request

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid inheritance doesn't work this way. Inheritance has to go "up or down", not both. If A inherits from B, B can't inherit from A.

Imagine a struct A, that holds a variable of type B, which is also a struct, which also holds a variable of type A:

```
public struct A
{
  public B data;
}

public struct B
{
  public A data;
}
```

If you tried to instantiate A, it would therefore also instantiate a variable of type B, which would in turn instantiate a variable of type A, and so on. You made a circular reference, so it will go in circles.

You have to find a more linear design. If you post your requirements in short, maybe we can help you out a bit.

Comment: i added aditional info based on your request